# visual studio 2022 version 17.6.1 setup completed with warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2022, incredibuild, visual-studio-installer

Visual studio 2022 update issue.

Visual Studio 2022 update 17.6.1 returns this error: setup completed with warnings and the package which is causing this error is Incredibuild

I tried to redo it but it seems not possible.

[image]